# Should it be possible to put the #load directive inside #if directive in F# fsx file?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, fable-f#

I have a fsx file where I try to do this

```
#if DEV
#load "MyFile.fs"
#endif

// Later in the file
#if DEV
callSomethingFromMyFile()
#endif
```

The `callSomethingFromMyFile()` works if I remove the `#if DEV ... #endif` around the `#load` directive.

I realize that this might be a weird thing, but it is because I'm using fable to compile to F# to js, and if I want to exclude a file when production "build" to reduce js file size.

Comment: have you tried not `#load` but `open MyFile.fs`?

Comment: obviously that should be `open MyFile`, also if you just work in FSI `#if INTERACTIVE` will let you wrap these statements (including the #load).

Comment: @s952163 the point being is that there is a difference on fsi directives, and on f# compiler/preprocessor directives, so obviously when in INTERACTIVE (yeah, fsi is running the show!) fsi directives like #load work. what happens outside of fsi, when its only the compiler/preprocessor taking care of the funs, is a totally different matter since #load is not a compiler/preprocessor directive.

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm Yes, of course. I was actually fuzzy on the use case, as in using FSI with dev and release, or fsi vs compiled. But I think wrapping `#load` and `open` with different flags (DEBUG, COMPILED, DEV, etc.) should get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive fixed this in the following PR: https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/pull/429

You can currently pass defines to the interactive checker its just that for fsx files this was not currently being done.

Answer (score 3):

In regular F# scripts it is possible, it seems like fable doesn't handle it.

To verify that it works in regular F# I created the following to files:

## MyModule.fs:

```
module MyModule
type A = {b: string}
```

## script.fsx:

```
#if DEV
#load "./MyModule.fs"
#endif

#if DEV
open MyModule
printfn "Hello A: %A" {b = "yolo"}
#endif
printfn "Done"
```

running `fsharpi --define:DEV --exec script.fsx` works as expected. I expect `fsi` on Windows to work as well.

Answer (score 2):

"
Some directives are available when you are executing scripts in F# Interactive that are not available when you are executing the compiler. The following table summarizes directives that are available when you are using F# Interactive.
"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/index#differences-between-the-interactive-scripting-and-compiled-environments

The table then lists #load amongst others. Not entirely clear that text (compiler vs. preprocessor), but it also kind of makes sense...